# How to reset top left of canvas after panning

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I built a simple "crop to element" function in fabricjs. http://jsfiddle.net/8azoap83/

After I resize the canvas, I am doing `absolutePan` to the top left of the element I am cropping to.
Instead of panning, I want to create a new top left for the canvas. something like: `canvas.resetTopLeftTo(top,left);`.

```
window.cropToRed = function(){
    gCanvas.setWidth(red.getWidth());
    gCanvas.setHeight(red.getHeight());

    var delta = new fabric.Point(red.getLeft(),red.getTop()) ;
    gCanvas.absolutePan(delta) ;
    //gCanvas.resetTopLeftTo(delta);//
    gCanvas.renderAll();
}
```

Thanks